# Zoom To Query result

Tags: query, zoom, search

I have SQL query in my code and after it responses I want to go to query result extent. What I have now is that after respond it goes somewhere in Atlantic ocean. Here is my code:

```
    //rukis Seqmna
     var map = new Map({
basemap: "topo",
layers: [resultsLayer]
        });
var view = new MapView({
container: "viewDiv", 
map: map, 
extent: { // Extent Chemi rukistvis()
        xmin: 5278000,
        ymin: 5147000,
        xmax: 4377000,
        ymax: 5247784,
        spatialReference: 102100
      }
    });



  //saZiebo panelis damateba (Widget)
    view.ui.add("infoDiv", "top-right");




   on(queryZebna, "click", function() {
        queryMagistraluri()
        .then(displayResults);



    });

    function queryMagistraluri() {
      var query = HWLayer.createQuery();
     //query.returnGeometry = true;
     //query.outFields = ["*"];
     let searchTerm = document.getElementById('searchInput').value;
     query.where = "სარწყავი_სისტემა LIKE N'%"+ searchTerm +"%'"; 
     query.outSpatialReference = view.spatialReference;
     return HWLayer.queryFeatures(query)

     .then(function(response) {
        view.goTo(response.extent);
      });







    // display the query results in the view

    function displayResults(results) {

      console.log(results);

      resultsLayer.removeAll();
      var features = results.features.map(function(graphica) {
        graphica.symbol = {
          type: "simple-line", // autocasts as new SimpleMarkerSymbol()
          style: "Solid",
          size: "50px",
          color: "#f0f"
        };
        return graphica




      });
      resultsLayer.addMany(features)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your map is using a projected coordinate system that is measured in metres and your database is using a geographic projection which is measured in degrees so when you use the results without reprojecting the coordinates are too small and you end up on Null Island.

Comment: I have set spatial reference after query, do i still have to set it?

Comment: It works, thank you @Ian Turton